# Java, calculating gross income by nesting an if then else inside a while loop

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple program to calculate the gross income of an employee. I'm reading an input file, then calculating the gross income. For some reason it only calculates the regular time, but not the overtime. I'm trying to nest an if then else inside a while loop. Any advice would be great, thanks!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        InputFile payroll;
        payroll = new InputFile("payroll.txt");

        String name, hours, payrate;
        Double p, h, finalpay;

        DecimalFormat numFormat;
        numFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");



        while(!payroll.eof())
        {    
            name = payroll.readString();
            hours = payroll.readWord();
            payrate = payroll.readWord();
            p = Double.parseDouble(payrate);
            h = Double.parseDouble(hours);
            if ( h > 40)
            {

                finalpay = (p * 40) + (( (h - 40) * 1.5) * p );
                System.out.println(name + " " + "gross pay is: " + numFormat.format(finalpay));
            }
            else
            {
                finalpay = (p * h);
                System.out.println(name + " " + "gross pay is: " + numFormat.format(finalpay));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? I'm not sure what's wrong with the logic, there's no reason an if/else block wouldn't belong here. Did you debug to check if any values are actually over 40?

Comment: Post your input file please

Comment: Hint: Change one of the println statements so you can see which path you're going through.

Comment: I don't receive any errors, but one employee works 45.5 hours but it calculates his time at straight time instead of overtime.

Comment: "Bob Jones" 10.25 40.00 
"Sam Smith" 15.00 45.50 
"Jodi White" 20.50 32.25

Comment: I would follow through with the debugger and make sure you're reading the right value and parseDouble is working properly, because I can't see why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 8):

Based on your input file provided in the comments:

```
"Bob Jones" 10.25 40.00 "Sam Smith" 15.00 45.50 "Jodi White" 20.50 32.25
```

Your program doesn't work as you expect it to because no employee in that list works more than 40 hours.  10.25, 15.00, and 20.50 are all less than 40.

Comment: Excellent catch. I did not see that the order was flipped and was going nuts trying to come up with the answer. +1

Comment: Yeah i'm an idiot, I changed the order that it was reading the file and it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not an idiot, it's an easy mistake. Learn to follow through with a debugger when this happens, so you could have verified what the value of h was. You would have seen that h was not right, which would have led you to the answer.

Comment: @hitztp - This is something that would have been obvious if you had made any sort of attempt to actually debug the code, either using an interactive debugger or just inserting println statements.